# Server Error in '/' Application

Tags: wcf

I have two wcf services. Their web.config files, methods and everything is the same. The code is the same. But, the first wcf service is working great, and the second says 'Server Error in '/' Application. The resource cannot be found.'/ I swear I'm going crazy.

The only thing I did else in the second wcf service is:
I deleted the IService1, Service1.svc and Service1.svc.cs files and added new named SomethingElse. Of course, the name of the project is different. That is the only thing that is different from the first web.config file.

I tried resolving this issue like this:

Changing

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
```

to

```
<authentication mode="None" />
```

No results.
I have Windows 7.

I now noticed this. When I'm adding a new item in my first project, it also says the same error.

Comment: How are you calling the services? How are you hosting them? IIS or otherwise? Are the hosting environments exactly the same?

Comment: @Josh Gallager I'm calling them on the same way. With this url:
http://localhost:1234/Service2.svc/myMetoda2/comeOn

Comment: @JoshGallagher They are self hosted.

Comment: I don't understand - are they both on the same URL? How are you switching between the two different services? It looks like you're hosting this in IIS. Have you looked in the Event Viewer to see if there's more information in there?

Comment: @JoshGallagher No, the URLs are different.
one is localhost:1234/Service2.svc/myMetoda2/comeOn , and the other is ocalhost:1234/MyNewService.svc/myMetoda2/comeOn

Comment: Comments crossed over there! Understood on the self hosting.

Comment: @JoshGallagher I'm becoming desperate, everything worked fine and now it's all for nothing :(
What should I see in the Event Viewer?

Comment: @JoshGallagher I think the problem happens with the services which are added as new items. But their path is the same.

Comment: @scree I moved this into a discussion room...

Comment: Sorry, tried to continue in the discussion room but it didn't work on my iPad. I'm not sure I'm going to be able to see you through this as I'm not near a computer to test it out, but at the moment there's not enough info in the question for others to be able to give the answer. I'm suspicious that the contents of one of the svc files may not point to a valid class any more, or maybe there's something in the web config file referencing something no longer existing. It's difficult to tell. simplify the problem down as much as possible, 1 service in each project, & post it in your question.

Comment: @JoshGallagher Do you want me to send you a link to my second wcf service?

Comment: @JoshGallagher I update my question. The error is only happening when the service is added as a new item in VS. The default service which is created bu the application works ok. If I add new service as a new item - error.

Comment: Can you post the name and the contents of the .svc file of one of the none working services, plus the code for its class?

Comment: @JoshGallagher The code is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8631626/when-i-add-new-item-wcf-service-an-error-happens-after-i-run-the-service

Comment: @JoshGallagher Also, can you see this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8631881/multiple-services-in-one-wcf-service-project