# Multiple services in one Wcf service project

Tags: wcf

I have one Wcf service project and in it many services called Service1, Service2 etc.

However, only Service1 is running. Why is this and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit vague description of your problem, but maybe this will help. I did a [post](http://blog4work.com/post/2011/06/25/How-to-host-many-WCF-services-in-one-Windows-Service.aspx) on how to host many WCF services in one windows service. If it doesn't help, check that your ABC(address, binding and contract) are set correctly.

Comment: 1. But did you by hand created IWindowsManagedService and WindowsManagedService or they are some sort of new item?
2, How do you mean 'installer class which is picked up by installutil'?

Comment: 2. And why did you separate the contract and the implementation? It's more confusing.

Comment: 1. IWindowsManagedService and WindowsManagedService are the Windows Service abstraction. They are needed to separate hosting plumbing (of Windows Service) from the actual work WCF service does. 2. Installutil is used to install Windows service into the internal service infrastructure, so I must have a class that is derived from ServiceBase system class that will have OnStart and OnStop members defined. 3. Abstraction is required because I can host many WCF services in one Windows service, it also helps to separate hosting details from actual WCF service.